# div instruction mflo does not print correct quotient

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
.data
    str: .asciiz "10010008"

.text
    addi $t2, $zero, 8
    lw $t6, str

    lb $t3, 7($t6)

    li $v0, 11
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall  # prints 8
        
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall # prints 8
    
    div $t3, $t2
    mfhi $t4
    mflo $t7    

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall  # prints 0 as expected, 8 % 8 = 0

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t7
    syscall  # prints 7, I expected it to print 0
```

Can anyone explain why `$t7` on the last line printed 7? I expected `div 8, 8` to print 0 in the quotient.

Comment: Looks entirely correct to me. If you're confused: A good starting point would be to assume the computer is not wrong here (this tends to be a decent first working hypothesis when working with computers in general). Once you accept this, you can start reasoning backwards from what the computer is telling you. What value would the computer have to have worked with to create this output? Also, the answer is literally in your code.

Comment: You expected 8/8 to be 0, not 1?  Why?  Did you mean to use the ASCII code as the dividend instead divisor, and actually do `8 / '8'`?  Otherwise you could get the remainder with `and $a0, $t3, (1<<3) - 1` (`$t3 & 7`), and the quotient with `srl $a0, $t3, 3`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using `lw` instead of `la`.
2. You are dividing an ascii character code, rather than a regular number,  so `'8' / 8` or 56 / 8.

Try using the debugger to see what is happening.